# Cant get response error text in Curl request

Tags: c, ajax, curl, request

I'm able to get HTTP response code like this:

```
curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &ResponseCode);
```

But how can I get response error text? I thought that CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER could help me:

```
char error_buf[CURL_ERROR_SIZE];
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, error_buf);
```

But it seems empty even if ResponseCode=500 and request status text returns (I'm sure about this because JQuery ajax request shows it). So how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true); //<= this is important, but not obvious
char error_buf[CURL_ERROR_SIZE];
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, error_buf);
```

It turns out, that despite HTTP response code 500 CURLcode was CURLE_OK - this is default behavior, and that is why was no error message in error_buf. CURLOPT_FAILONERROR forces Curl to convert all response codes >= 300 to errors.

Answer (score 0):

Return value of `curl_easy_perform` can be passed to `curl_easy_strerror` to get a text represent of the error. It may not be the 'response error' you wanted, but helps to get the reason why the request end with code like 500.

Comment: As you mentioned, curl_easy_strerror return only text description of response code. Real error message returns in CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER.